# Why it need to align when try to allocate new memory in C

Tags: c, memory-management

Now I am reading the C interface and implementations.The fourth charted is memory management.It said that the alighment ensures that any type of data can be stored in the blocks returne by Mem_alloc function.How can I understand this sentence?Is it necessary to align when manamenent memory?

The align code is as below:

```
union align {
#ifdef MAXALIGN
        char pad[MAXALIGN];
#else
        int i;
        long l;
        long *lp;
        void *p;
        void (*fp)(void);
        float f;
        double d;
        long double ld;
#endif
void *Mem_alloc(long nbytes, const char *file, int line){
        struct descriptor *bp;
        void *ptr;
        assert(nbytes > 0);
        nbytes = ((nbytes + sizeof (union align) - 1)/
                (sizeof (union align)))*(sizeof (union align));
        for (bp = freelist.free; bp; bp = bp->free) {
                if (bp->size > nbytes) {
                        bp->size -= nbytes;
                        ptr = (char *)bp->ptr + bp->size;
                        if ((bp = dalloc(ptr, nbytes, file, line)) != NULL) {
                                unsigned h = hash(ptr, htab);
                                bp->link = htab[h];
                                htab[h] = bp;
                                return ptr;
                        } else
                                {
                                        if (file == NULL)
                                                RAISE(Mem_Failed);
                                        else
                                                Except_raise(&Mem_Failed, file, line);
                                }
                }
                if (bp == &freelist) {
                        struct descriptor *newptr;
                        if ((ptr = malloc(nbytes + NALLOC)) == NULL
                        ||  (newptr = dalloc(ptr, nbytes + NALLOC,
                                        __FILE__, __LINE__)) == NULL)
                                {
                                        if (file == NULL)
                                                RAISE(Mem_Failed);
                                        else
                                                Except_raise(&Mem_Failed, file, line);
                                }
                        newptr->free = freelist.free;
                        freelist.free = newptr;
                }
        }
        assert(0);
        return NULL;
}
    };

 void *Mem_resize(void *ptr, long nbytes,
        const char *file, int line) {
        struct descriptor *bp;
        void *newptr;
        assert(ptr);
        assert(nbytes > 0);
        if (((unsigned long)ptr)%(sizeof (union align)) != 0
        || (bp = find(ptr)) == NULL || bp->free)
                Except_raise(&Assert_Failed, file, line);
        newptr = Mem_alloc(nbytes, file, line);
        memcpy(newptr, ptr,
                nbytes < bp->size ? nbytes : bp->size);
        Mem_free(ptr, file, line);
        return newptr;
}
```

How can I understand these codes?Why it need to if (((unsigned long)ptr)%(sizeof (union align)) != 0 when resize the space?

Comment: What user11... said.  But otherwise I have no idea what question you're asking.  In general, unless your playing strange games, you need not worry about alignment -- the OS and compiler take care of it for you.

Answer (score 1):

CPUs have limitations in handling data. For example, pointers generally have to be 4-byte aligned for 32-bit CPUs and 8-byte aligned for 64-bit CPUs. Furthermore, there can be performance penalties for loading and storing data on non-aligned boundaries when it is allowed. A CPU might be able to load from an odd address, for example, but it will take twice as many cycles. This is often because the memory hardware is optimized for grabbing data on 4, 8, or 16 byte boundaries, and will have to load the lower part of the data word in one cycle, then load the upper part in the next cycle.

So when implementing a compiler, you want it to work well on CPUs that have these alignment needs.

[See here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/data-alignment-when-migrating-to-64-bit-intel-architecture/) for an example of Intel's IA-64 alignment requirements:

> - Align 8-bit data at any address
> - Align 16-bit data to be contained within an aligned four-byte word
> - Align 32-bit data so that its base address is a multiple of four
> - Align 64-bit data so that its base address is a multiple of eight
> - Align 80-bit data so that its base address is a multiple of sixteen
> - Align 128-bit data so that its base address is a multiple of sixteen

Comment: I was under the impression (could be wrong) that `malloc` is required to return memory that's sufficiently aligned for any standard C type (usually aligned to 64-bit/8 byte boundaries these days). Arrays, structs etc certainly ensure alignment of components assuming the structure as a whole is aligned. So AFAIK, alignment only becomes an issue if you have types that may have larger alignment than the standard C types - things like SIMD registers (and structs/arrays/unions that contain them) - or if you define layouts at run-time using `sizeof` and pointer arithmetic.